# NetSuite - importing Bills and Bill Payment

Tags: netsuite

I've created a template to import bills and that seems to work. Having issues with the bill payment. Error: **You must enter at least one line item for this transaction**.

I've taken the bill internal ID and mapped it to the Vendor Payment Bills > Bill field. Is that the correct mapping? I tried setting the Vendor Payments Bill > 'Line' field to 0 and then 1 but no luck. Also, it asks for an external Id or an 'order / invoice no, which I don't have.

Also - I can't map my csv status field. I tried using integer values like 1,2,3, string like pending approval as well as VendBill:A - no luck. What's the correct way to map to status field?

Comment: Transaction statuses are notoriously difficult to work with. Try using just "A" instead of "VendBill:A". I'm not exactly sure how importing Bills via CSV works, but the error message you're receiving indicates you haven't put any line items on the Bill you're trying to save.

Comment: Cool - the "A" works, thanks. Just need to figure out how to import the bill payments now!

Answer (score 0):

### Bill imports require two CSV files!

One contains the "header" information and each row represents a unique bill.  This is the part of the bill that hits accounts payable.  The other CSV file contains the "line" information or how the bill is coded.  Each line in the header file must have at least one row of data in the line file, but you can have more than one.

**The "Ref No" Field**

NetSuite uses a field called "Ref No" to match data from the two files together.  You need a "Ref No" column in both the "Header" and "Line" files.

**The Header File**

Your header file should have sequential numbers in your "Ref No" column (e.g.1, 2, 3, 4...) on each row and each should be unique.  They are only used to assist with the import process and don't actually show up in your NetSuite transaction data.

[image: Example of a bill "Header" CSV import]

**The Line File**

Your line file should reference the ref numbers from the header file.  For example, assuming you gave your first bill a "Ref No" of "1", and that bill has two rows of coding data, your line file should have two rows of data using "1" as the "Ref No".

Since the line file is matched to the header file, you don't need to duplicate data that is already in the header file, such as the transaction/document number, vendor name, date, etc.

[image: Example of a bill "line" CSV import]

Keep in mind that your field names and required fields may be different but the basic principles are the same.

Bill payments may need to be imported after the bills, if you want to show a link between the bill payment and the bills that were paid.

Comment: Great answer, but it's not quite true that bills always require a multi-file import, unless the bills include expenses data.

Comment: Can you give an example of a bill that does not require a multi-file import?  Do you mean bills with only one line of expense data?

Comment: Any bills with expenses data _do_ need multi-file.  Bills with just header and item lines (and no expenses) can be imported using single or multi-file.  See [SuiteAnswer 10020](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10020).